# Printing with delimiter only between values

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I have a slight problem with the output of my code and been searching for such topics same as with this but I don't find any.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");    
    n = sc.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print(n + "! = ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
        System.out.printf("%d x " , i);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The output must be. Whenever I type integer. e.g 5.

```
Enter a positive integer: 5
5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5
```

But the slight problem is that the output goes like this `5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x`

There's extra x on the last number which should not be there

Comment: What you're saying is that you should print "x" *if* `i` is not equals to `n`...

Comment: That is a factorial, it should be `5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5` but whenever I run my code it gives me extra " x "

Comment: I know what that is. But *if* (hint hint) you re-read my comment carefully, the solution is in there.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't know *if* it's gone over their head that hint.

Comment: Well, the problem now is I don't get the last number

Comment: @1337 If none of the 3 given answers was able to solve your issue, downvote them and provide a comment on the answers explaining why they did not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### StringJoiner

Others already answered how to fix your code but I would like to provide you with a more *professional* solution, namely by using a `StringJoiner`.

With this, you can give a delimiter, prefix and suffix, then just add all your elements and the `StringJoiner` will make sure that the delimiter is only added in between. It takes all the work from you. Here is the code:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("x ", n + "! = ", "");
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sj.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
System.out.println(sj);
```

---

### Streams

If you prefer streams:

```
String result = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("x ", n + "! = ", ""));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Sir, May I ask. I used the `while loop` right so, the factorial value keeps going up which it shouldn't. Now when the user input is `5 = 120` but for the second time the user inputs `4 = 2880` it goes something like that which `4!` should be `= 24`

Comment: I dont follow. You will have to share your code, output and expected output. Also, this sounds like a different question which you may just post as a new question instead. The code provided here works, use it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
System.out.printf("%d x " ,i);
```

by this:

```
if (i == n)
   System.out.printf("%d" ,i);
else
   System.out.printf("%d x " ,i);
```

This way you avoid printing "x" when you print the last number in the factorization.

Comment: While your answer solves the issue, please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), especially the part about answering.

Comment: It would help if you also add a short explanation of why this fixes the issue. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for the information, it did not come to my mind the homework thing.

Comment: @Zabuzard thanks for the advice, I added some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can do this:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");    
    n = sc.nextInt();
   
    String result = "";
    System.out.print(n + "! = ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
        result += i + " x ";
    }
    System.out.println(result.substring(0, result.length() - 3);
}
```

Comment: While this works, this is kind of a bad approach to this. It is hard to read and understand, especially the "magic value" `3` and easily breaks if the delimiter is changed.