# Prevent trailing character when printing values in a loop

Tags: java

I was tasked to do a looping problem for Java, but I'm currently having a problem on how to display a factorial of a number. For example, 1x2x3x4x5 = 120.

I'm almost there, but I can't seem to figure out how to, or is there any possible way to display the factorial of a number because there is always an additional "x" at the end of the 5.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class trylangpo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int fctr;
        System.out.println ("number");
        fctr = input.nextInt();
    
        for (int i = 1; i <=fctr; i++){
            System.out.print(i);
    
            int j;
            for (j =1; j <=1 ; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Example output:

```
1x2x3x4x5x
```

Comment: Is there a factorial epidemic going around? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089542/printing-with-delimiter-only-between-values?noredirect=1#comment115072370_65089542

Comment: not solving your problem but just pointing out that your loop `for (j =1; j <=1 ; j++)` can be removed. it only loops once so, just write  `System.out.print("*");`. no loop required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a condition if it’s not at the end of the loop. Then add start and if it’s the end, then just print the number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fctr;
    System.out.println("number");
    fctr = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= fctr; i++) {
        if (i < fctr) {
            System.out.print(i + " * ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop for `(j =1; j <=1 ; j++)` can be removed. It only loops once so, just write `System.out.print("*")`. No loop required

Then if you think about it, you want to print the number and the `*` all the time, except when it is the last number (`fctr`)

So write it that way:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int fctr;
System.out.println ("number");
fctr = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <=fctr; i++){
    System.out.print(i);

    if(i<fctr) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use a construct like

```
String sep="";
for (...) {
   System.out.print(sep);
   System.out.print(payload);
   sep="x";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the printing of ***** condition. Don't print ***** if `i == fctr`. And you don't need that additional loop of `j`. As below :

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fctr;
    System.out.println("number");
    fctr = input.nextInt();

    //    IntStream.range(1, fctr).

    long factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= fctr; i++) {
      factorial = factorial * i;
      if (i == fctr) {
        System.out.print(i);
      } else {
        System.out.print(i + "*");
      }
    }

    System.out.print("=" + factorial);
  }
```